# pass value from one page to another page using post in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys i have one `<td>` column where it will represent for edit row for that particular record. So when i click on the edit  it  is passing id value to next page through GET. But now i want to pass that id to next page using POST.

Can any one help me how to pass it id value from one page to another page using POST

Here is my code:

```
<tbody>
    <?php 
        global $DB; 
        if ($_SESSION[ 'idnumber']==1 ) { 
            $retval="SELECT * FROM mdl_ppc_company mpc  where status='1' ORDER BY mpc.cid " ; 
        } 
        $companydeactivate = $DB->get_records_sql($retval); 
        if (sizeof($companydeactivate)): 
            foreach ($companydeactivate as $row): 
                if ($_SESSION['idnumber'] == 3 && $row->idnumber == 3) 
                { 
                    continue; 
                } 
                else { ?>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>
            <?php echo $row->company; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row->createdby; ?></td>
        <td>
            <center>
                <a href="editcompany.php">
                    <img src="images/header_icon/Icon_10.png" style="background-color:teal; width:25px; height:25px; border-radius: 4px" alt="edit_btn">
                </a>
            </center>
        </td>
        <?php if ($row->level == '1') { ?>
        <td>
            <center>
                <a href="companydeactivate.php?id=<?php echo $row->cid; ?>" onclick="" class="disabled">
                    <img src="images/header_icon/icon_delete.png" style="background-color:#c30c0c; width:25px; height:25px; border-radius: 4px" alt="delete_btn">
                </a>
            </center>
        </td>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <td>
            <center>
                <a href="companydeactivate.php?id=<?php echo $row->cid; ?>" onclick="">
                    <img src="images/header_icon/icon_delete.png" style="background-color:#c30c0c; width:25px; height:25px; border-radius: 4px" alt="delete_btn">
                </a>
            </center>
        </td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } endforeach; endif; ?>
</tbody>
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TarangP thanks for editing can you please  help me how to solve that issue

Comment: have you used ajax /

Comment: Why do you want to use POST? GET makes more sense. GET is for getting a resource (like the edit page) while POST is for sending data to be processed by the server.

Comment: yes but because if i used get its showing id in URL. so user can edit id and can  make changes right?so for that purpose i would like to use POST

Comment: @TarangP no i didn't use ajax that much

Comment: Try the AJEX for POST and why do you want to use POST while you can easily retrieve value using GET ?

Comment: Sure, but they will be able to do that using POST as well. You still need to put the ID somewhere in your code so anyone can change that if they really want to. If users are only allowed to edit specific ID's, you need to check if they are allowed to edit the ID on the edit page before showing the edit page. You need to do this regardless of how you send the ID. The ID shouldn't be a secret.

Comment: so is there no problem using GET ?

Comment: No. Sending the ID through GET is pretty standard. It's the edit page that needs to check if the user is allowed to edit that ID or not.

Comment: ok thank you Magnus. i will go with GET

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Example

```
    <img src="images/header_icon/Icon_10.png" style="background-color:teal; width:25px; height:25px; border-radius: 4px" 
alt="edit_btn" onclick="post('editcompany.php', {id: '<?php echo $row->cid; ?>'})">
```